# Help with Finding ∂z/∂u and ∂z/∂v

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find $∂z/∂u$ and $∂z/∂v$.
The variables are restricted to domains on which the functions are defined.
$z = \sin(x/y)$, $x = \ln u$, $y = 7v$

I solved for both ∂z/∂u and ∂z/∂v but cannot figure how to only express the answers in terms of u/v. ∂z/∂u came out to (1/y)(1/u)(cos(x/y)) and ∂z/∂v as (-x/y^2)(cos(x/y))(7).

Comment: Do you know the chain rule? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I solved it for both ∂z/∂u and ∂z/∂v but cannot figure how to only express the answers in terms of u/v.

Comment: acraft, If you want the answer in a certain form, you should make this wish clear inside your main text, not in the comments. Also you should show the work you've done. (in the main text above)

Comment: I'm new to StackExchange and will keep your tip in mind. ∂z/∂u came out to (1/y)(1/u)(cos(x/y)) and  ∂z/∂v as (-x/y^2)(cos(x/y))(7).  The problem is with solving for x,y so the final answers are in terms of u,v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT

Your calculation is correct.

You have an expression with $x$, $y$, $u$, and $v$. To get an expression with just $u$ and $v$, use the fact that you know what $x$ and $y$ are, i.e., substitute $\ln u$ everywhere you have $x$ and $7v$ everywhere you have $y$.

Comment: Can you explain why I need the term ∂z/∂y⋅∂y/∂u? Since z is a function of x,y; x is a function of u; y is a function of v. I have ∂z/∂u=∂z/∂x*∂x/∂u and ∂z/∂v=∂z/∂y*∂y/∂v. Did I make an error?

Comment: My apologies, you are right! I didn't follow through with the calculation. The answer is correct, and I hope the last paragraph answered your actual question then!

Comment: No worries! By any chance is it possible to solve for ∂z/∂u in terms of only u and ∂z/∂v in terms of only v?

Comment: Does my answer not make sense for how to get that?

Comment: Yes it does, but I guess my answer is still not accepted by the grading system. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is substitute the given functions, either before or after you apply the chain rule. For example, $x = \ln u$ so you just replace all the $x$ terms in your $\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}$ with $\ln u$, and similarly for $y$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. I ended up cos(lnu/7v)*(1/7vu) and cos(lnu/v)*(-lnu/7v^2), but I guess the grading system prefers another answer format??? Your explanation makes sense! Thank you for your time.

Comment: It might want you to rearrange things a bit - for example, to put the - sign out the front and put some parentheses around terms to avoid ambiguity (e.g. does 1/7vu mean $\frac{1}{7vu}$ or $\frac{1}{7} vu$ or something else?)